# Fastest Way to Update Product Custom Attributes and Product Name, Product Weight using csv in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, custom, csv, custom-attributes

We want update existing created products Product Name, Product Weight and custom attributes using csv file.
We have csv  file and want compare existing created Product SKU in website with Product SKU in csv file then we need to update custom attributes like (Product Name, Product Weight and other differnt custom attributes ).
How to do is there any way or solution please share.

Comment: you want to fastest and bulk update any attribute ??? If yes check this link https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-update-attribute-sets-in-bulk.html . why this solution because this is easy and fast

Comment: Thank you @MohitPatel , but i want custom script, we want update daily product values automatically  using cronjob file. we have around 60K Existing products  in our website and want update daily  for product limited fields using csv file.
is there any custom  php script using custom script csv data can read and using sku we can get data from data base and update related fileds for products

Answer (score 0):

Align sku in ascending order in excel add missing sku's with empty data to remove the differences of both files.
when both file have same sku align in ascending order you can copy past data and import.it will take a while but i'll work

Comment: Thank you @Izhar Mehdi,    but i want custom script, we want update daily product values automatically using cronjob file. we have around 60K Existing products in our website and want update daily for product limited fields using csv file. is there any custom php script using custom script csv data can read and using sku we can get data from data base and update related fileds for products

Comment: script depends on data, so i don't think you can find any script that can exactly process your data but you can find a similar one, that ca be change accordingly

https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02_ZE3wIvnOlciSuc_LNu1XxOCMgw%3A1592660655291&ei=rxLuXviaEfPkgwfvh7_wAQ&q=magento+1+csv+data+process+script+github&oq=magento+1+csv+data+process+script+github&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQR1D7twFY_LgBYLK6AWgAcAF4AIABrAKIAawCkgEDMy0xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi4ruykw5DqAhVz8uAKHe_DDx4Q4dUDCAw&uact=5